Is Bhagavad Gita 6.27 a clear endorsement of Advaitic, non-theistic realization?
https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/6/verse/27#:~:text=BG%206.27%3A%20Great%20transcendental%20happiness%20comes%20to%20the,and%20who%20sees%20everything%20in%20connection%20with%20God.

प्रशान्तमनसं ह्येनं योगिनं सुखमुत्तमम् |
उपैति शान्तरजसं ब्रह्मभूतमकल्मषम् || 27||


praśhānta-manasaṁ hyenaṁ yoginaṁ sukham uttamam
upaiti śhānta-rajasaṁ brahma-bhūtam akalmaṣham


BG 6.27: Great transcendental happiness comes to the yogi whose mind is calm, whose passions are subdued, who is without sin, and who sees everything in connection with God.

The translation is a theistically biased false translation (there is enormous misinformation about Hindu scripture out there).
"brahmabhutam" obviously means "one who has become Brahman"
here is a better translation:
https://shlokam.org/bhagavad-gita/6-27/

प्रशान्तमनसं ह्येनं योगिनं सुखमुत्तमम् ।
उपैति शान्तरजसं ब्रह्मभूतमकल्मषम् ॥ ६-२७॥


praśāntamanasaṃ hyenaṃ yoginaṃ sukhamuttamam
upaiti śāntarajasaṃ brahmabhūtamakalmaṣam 6-27


Supreme Bliss verily comes to this YOGI, whose mind is quite peaceful, whose passion is quietened, who is free from sin, and who has become BRAHMAN.

there is no God or any deity in this translation.
Pure reflection of advaitic mahavakyas like "Aham Brahmasmi".

Bhagavad Gita gives multiple paths for moksha.

Our Madhwist and Srivaishnavite friends may not agree @estimator

Yes. It is possible. Such phrase is also found in Bhagavata Purana.

प्रतिरुद्धेन्द्रियप्राणमनोबुद्धिमुपारतम् । स्थानत्रयात्परं
प्राप्तं ब्रह्मभूतमविक्रियम् ॥ २६ ॥
The muni’s sense organs, breath, mind and intelligence were all
restrained from material activities, and he was situated in a trance
apart from the three [wakefulness, dream and unconsciousness], having
achieved a transcendental position qualitatively equal with the
Supreme Absolute.
[Bhagavata Purana 1.18.26]

In the Iskcon translation given above the translator added a phrase qualitatively into the translation to give a biased view. In reality there is no equivalent word for qualitatively in the original Sanskrit verse.
Alternate translation by G.V. Tagare:

Parīkṣit whose palate was completely dried up, asked water from the
sage who had thus controlled his sense-organs, life-breath, mind and
intellect (completely) and (had his heart) detached (from external
objects), who had attained (the fourth stage) beyond the three stages
(of wakefulness, dream and sleep) and was merged in Brahman. in
perfect serenity. (He was) covered with the dishevelled locks of his
matted hair and had put on the hide of a Ruru-deer(26-27).


Although ISKCON has become largely Indian and are simply running their temples as Krishna temples - all their crypto-abrahamic ("supreme personality of godhead") translations must be discarded.  Do you know of a non-ISKCON translation of Krishna Bhagavatam online? @cracklingcyclone

@SK I think this translation of Bhagavatam is not associated with Iskcon. https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-bhagavata-purana

please add the wisdomlib translation and I'll accept the answer @estimator

@SK The OP found the sloka. It would be unfair for me to copy his reference. It is 1.18.27.

please add the wisdomlib translation and I'll accept the answer @cracklingcyclone

@SK added alternate translation

Also see Bhagavad Gita 18.54 @SK

devotion to a deity after Advaitic realization can at best be a pastime. @CracklingCyclone
